# Does the constructor call have to be the first statement in the constructor?

Tags: java, android

I have a class cShape to handle graphic images.  It takes the starting position in its constructor.  I would like the starting position to be random, so I have the following code

```
cBalloon(Context InContext, int w, int h) {
    // set up random postion
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    int sx=randomGenerator.nextInt(w);
    int sy=randomGenerator.nextInt(h);

    super( InContext,  sx,  sy,  0,0,  50,50,  "balloon", 50,50,0);
}
```

I get a error saying "`Constructor class must be first in a constructor`"
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: yes. it has to be first in the constructor

Comment: Just call a method in the super constructor which generate numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of workable pragmatic solutions here, but it bothered me that none are truly general for this class of task.  A general solution would work for some data source which was not truly random, ie, where it matters that you get both values from the *same* instance.  And it would be nice to avoid static variables, even temporary ones, for cleanliness and easy thread safety.

So here's my idea: have one constructor which invokes another, passing it a temporary instance of the data source Random(), which it will use to get both values.

```
public class cBalloon {

    public cBalloon(Context inContext, int w, int h) {
        this( inContext,  new Random(), w, h);
    }

    public cBalloon(Context inContext, Random randomGenerator, int w, int h) {
        super(inContext,  
              randomGenerator.nextInt(w),  
              randomGenerator.nextInt(h),  
              0,0,  50,50,  "balloon", 50,50,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code.  Seems like there would be a more clean way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The `super(...)` must be a first statement in the constructor.

But, there is a workaround: create a static method

```
private static int getRandomtInt(int x) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    return randomGenerator.nextInt(x);
}
```

and call it in a super constructor:

```
cBalloon(Context InContext, int w, int h) {
    super( InContext,  getRandomInt(w),  getRandomInt(h),  0,0,  50,50,  "balloon", 50,50,0);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do super(InContext, (new Random).nextInt(w)...) ?  However neither your solution nor this is precisely equivalent to the original, since the random numbers are now coming from *different* instances of Random rather than the same - which given that such things are only pseudorandom could arguably matter depending on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `super(..)` should be the first statement in the constructor.

You basically have four options:

1) You can call directly to the constructor like this

```
cBalloon(Context InContext, int randx, int randY int w, int h, Random randomGenerator) {
         super(InContext, randomGenerator.nextInt(w), randomGenerator.nextInt(h), ...)     
}
```

2) Or you can get the random variables BEFORE calling the constructor

```
cBalloon(Context InContext, int randx, int randY int w, int h){
      super(InContext, randx, randY, 0, 0, ...);
}
```

3) Create a static method that will generate the random number every time you call it. This will keep you constructor method very clean, which is good.

```
private static int getRandomInteger(final int x) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    return randomGenerator.nextInt(x);
}

cBalloon(Context InContext, int w, int h){
      super(InContext, getRandomInteger(w), getRandomInteger(h), 0, 0, ...);
}
```

4) Just generate the random numbers in the super class.

There is no need to declare those integer variables `sx` and `sy` like that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where does randomGenerator get declared and initialized?

Comment: You can pass it to the Constructor.

Comment: But that's changing the requirement.

Comment: who said that the requirements could not be changed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the super like that. The super function must be called first in the cBalloon constructor. So you would need to pass the random numbers directly to it.
Like so:

```
cBalloon(Context InContext, int randx, int randY int w, int h)
{
    super( InContext,  randX,  randY,  0,0,  50,50,  "balloon", 50,50,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

super or this should be the first statement in the constructor. You can do it like this

```
super(InContext, new Random().nextInt(w), new Random().nextInt(h), 
      0, 0, 50, 50, "balloon", 50, 50, 0)
```

OR Even this

```
class cBalloon{
Random randomGenerator=new Random();
cBalloon(Context InContext, int w, int h) {
    // set up random postion


    super( InContext,  randomGenerator.nextInt(w),  randomGenerator.nextInt(h),  0,0,  50,50,  "balloon", 50,50,0);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Probably okay practically for most purposes, but not quite the same, since two different instances of Random are now being used.  So in effect this isn't a general solution to the type of problem contemplated by the question, though it may be a useful solution to writing that particular program.